# Why does echo >file use more real time than echo | sed >file?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, time, echo

The example, below, surprised me. It seems to be counter intuitive... aside from the fact that there is a whisker more *user time* for the `echo | sed` combo.

Why is `echo` using so much *sys time* when it runs alone, or should the question be, How does `sed` change the state of play?  It seems that `echo` would needs to do the same *echo-ing* in both cases...

```
time echo -n a\ {1..1000000}\ c$'\n' >file

# real    0m9.481s
# user    0m5.304s
# sys     0m4.172s

time echo -n a\ {1..1000000}\ c$'\n' |sed s/^\ // >file

# real    0m5.955s
# user    0m5.488s
# sys     0m1.580s
```

Comment: My gut reaction is it has to do with buffering.

Comment: @bahamat I think you're right. The echo does a separate write() for each argument. The sed buffers them. So the first version has a million writes to a regular file, going through a filesystem driver into the block device layer, and the second version has a million writes going into a pipe and somewhat fewer writes going through the more expensive layers of kernel code.

Comment: @bahamat Definitely buffering. `time echo ... |cat >file` and even `time echo ... |perl -ne 'print'` are similar times to the `sed` version.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the good explanations... So for big multi-line writes (in bash), cat has gained a Useful Use of Cat point :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

bahamat and Alan Curry have it right: this is due to the way your shell buffers the output of `echo`. Specifically, your shell is bash, and it issues one `write` system call per line. Hence the first snippet makes 1000000 writes to a disk file, whereas the second snippet makes 1000000 writes to a pipe and sed (largely in parallel, if you have multiple CPUs) makes a considerably smaller number of writes to a disk file due to its output buffering.

You can observe what's going on by running [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace).

```
$ strace -f -e write bash -c 'echo -n a\ {1..2}\ c$'\'\\n\'' >file'
write(1, "a 1 c\n", 6)                  = 6
write(1, " a 2 c\n", 7)                 = 7
$ strace -f -e write bash -c 'echo -n a\ {1..2}\ c$'\'\\n\'' | sed "s/^ //" >file'
Process 28052 attached
Process 28053 attached
Process 28051 suspended
[pid 28052] write(1, "a 1 c\n", 6)      = 6
[pid 28052] write(1, " a 2 c\n", 7)     = 7
Process 28051 resumed
Process 28052 detached
Process 28051 suspended
[pid 28053] write(1, "a 1 c\na 2 c\n", 12) = 12
Process 28051 resumed
Process 28053 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
```

Other shells such as ksh buffer the output of `echo` even when it's multiline, so you won't see much of a difference.

```
$ strace -f -e write ksh -c 'echo -n a\ {1..2}\ c$'\'\\n\'' >file'
write(1, "a 1 c\n a 2 c\n", 13)         = 13
$ strace -f -e write ksh -c 'echo -n a\ {1..2}\ c$'\'\\n\'' | sed "s/^ //" >file'
Process 28058 attached
[pid 28058] write(1, "a 1 c\n a 2 c\n", 13) = 13
Process 28058 detached
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
write(1, "a 1 c\na 2 c\n", 12)          = 12
```

With bash I get similar timing ratios. With ksh I see the second snippet running slower.

```
ksh$ time echo -n a\ {1..1000000}\ c$'\n' >file

real    0m1.44s
user    0m1.28s
sys     0m0.06s
ksh$ time echo -n a\ {1..1000000}\ c$'\n' | sed "s/^ //" >file

real    0m2.38s
user    0m1.52s
sys     0m0.14s
```

Comment: Thanks... That last `ksh` example is more along the lines of what I expected...